# How should I delete the file after plot being generated in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, web

I have a Flask app, in which the user uploads a .csv, my app treats it with a bit of pandas and stuff and creates plots from it. Really simple: A form to upload the file, and a button with "Plot!" which refreshes the page with the exhibited plots.

My question is: **What is the best practice to delete the file after the user press the "Plot!"?**

My folder is getting full really click on my pythonanywhere host. Also, some friends were testing, and some were seeing plots from others' files. I was googling some topics about sessions and stuff, but since I don't know what I don't know, my searches are really poor.

Also, I want a simple page, without the necessity of user login etc. Can you guys help me out with it? Or at least guide me on what topics to read about.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use epoch time for csv filenames. Here is how you get it:

```
import time
filename = str(time.time())+".csv"
```

And write a function to list dir and auto remove. Put this into post part, so in every upload it will check for useless files and remove them.

```
import os
static_files = os.listdir("static")
for s in static_files:
    if ".csv" in s:
        #Gives the epoch time when you saved the file as seconds.
        time_name = float(s.split(".")[0])
        current_time = time.time()
        if time_name+300<current_time:
             os.system(f"rm static/{s}")
```

Definitions: Epoch time -> number of seconds passed from first day of 1970.
Other ways: You can add the second code block into a while loop and run it at the background to automatically remove it. Also it will be healthier but if it was my project I would put it in app.py
You also mentioned that it returns some users someone else's plot. You can solve it by plotting it in another endpoint and load it as img in HTML. You need to use the async matplotlib and return it as bytes with filetype png header.
You can check it out here:[Need help in flask to generate dynamic graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76542334/need-help-in-flask-to-generate-dynamic-graphs/76544780#76544780)

Comment: Be careful with this: if users even get to choose part of the name of any file in `static/`, you've just handed them the keys to your server. Instead consider using `os.remove` or `pathlib.Path.unlink`.